# Elegant solution for two Optionals, if one is present the other must not be empty

Tags: java, option-type

I look for a more elegant solution of this code:

```
var first = Optional.ofNullable(a);
var second = Optional.ofNullable(b);
if ((unit.isPresent() && value.isEmpty()) || (value.isPresent() && 
     unit.isEmpty())) {
  throw new ExpWhatever();
}
```

Conditions are:

- if both optionals are null -> ok, no error/excpt.
- if one of the given optionals is present the other must not be empty too (otherwise: excpt.)

Thanks for any ideas or help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like it's an error for `isPresent()` to be true for exactly one of them - so XOR works well:

```
if (unit.isPresent() ^ value.isPresent()) {
    // Throw an exception
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want both optionals to be either present or empty (i.e. they have the same "emptiness" state), you could use this:

```
if (unit.isPresent() != value.isPresent()) {
  //throw an exception
}
```